# OpenCV2 ---> OpenCV4

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-zero-w, raspicam, opencv, javascript

I have been working on a project from github, https://github.com/twilio/wireless-security-camera, that utilizes OpenCV. Now I haven't played much with OpenCV so this is trial and error on my part. Looking at the script i was running into issue due to its dependance on OpenCV2 functions. I started diving in to OpenCV4 and think im on the right track.

The script had a function called CV.readimage, when running this script the script would constantly run and not complete the "capture" of "previousimage & im" to compare for differences. So my first change was to change this function to CV.imreadAsync. Once I did this the script now will grab both images and proceed to the next line in the script. The next couple lines in the script i am unsure what needs to change and could really use a nudge in the right direction.

````
```Javascript file security-camera.js```

     if (previousImage && im.width() > 1 && im.height() > 1) {
     CV.ImageSimilarity(im, previousImage, function (err, dissimilarity) {
      console.log('Dissimilarity:', dissimilarity);
      previousImage = im;
````

heres a printout of the script when ran with the command NPM start.

````
 ```NPM Start```     
pi@raspberrypi:~/camera $ npm start

    > wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start /home/pi/camera

    > node security-camera.js

    Got configuration for camera: cameraid

    Snapshot document: ETfce4dca035cb45cc9575479757d48d18

    Control map: MPb7bbd87e79b24ab6a9aff3db19b085cb

    Starting camera capture

    calling....

    /opt/vc/bin/raspistill --width 640 --height 360 --output /home/pi/camera/images/ camera%03d.jpg --nopreview --timeout 1800000 --timelapse 250 --quality 80 --rotation 180 --thumb 0:0:0

    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    raspicam::watcher::event change

    raspicam::watcher::event change

    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    Frame captured: null 1579706071810 camera000.jpg

    stderr: mmal: Skipping frame 1 to restart at frame 2



    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    CV loaded: /home/pi/camera/images/camera000.jpg Mat {

    step: 1920,

    elemSize: 3,

    sizes: [ 360, 640 ],

    empty: 0,

    depth: 0,

    dims: 2,

    channels: 3,

    type: 16,

    cols: 640,

    rows: 360

    }

    raspicam::watcher::event change

    raspicam::watcher::event change

    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    raspicam::watcher::event rename

    Frame captured: null 1579706072527 camera002.jpg

    stderr: mmal: Skipping frame 3 to restart at frame 5



    CV loaded: /home/pi/camera/images/camera002.jpg Mat {

    step: 1920,

    elemSize: 3,

    sizes: [ 360, 640 ],

    empty: 0,

    depth: 0,

    dims: 2,

    channels: 3,

    type: 16,

    cols: 640,

    rows: 360

    }

    /home/pi/camera/security-camera.js:115

    if (previousImage && im.width() > 1 && im.height() > 1) {

    ^

    TypeError: im.width is not a function

    at /home/pi/camera/security-camera.js:115:30

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! errno 1

    npm ERR! wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start: \node security-camera.js\``

    npm ERR! Exit status 1

    npm ERR!

    npm ERR! Failed at the wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start script.

    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
   additional logging output 

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

    npm ERR! /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-01-22T15_14_32_661Z-debug.log
````

**Update** with info from comment:
The next couple lines in the script i am unsure what needs to change. My question is how can i make the script compare the two images to determine if there was a change that it should send a notification. Previously the script pulled width and height before running a "similarity" function. When running the script using opencv4nodejs it fails at width, height, and imagesimilarity saying all the above is not a function.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Ingo The next couple lines in the script i am unsure what needs to change. My question is how can i make the script  compare the two images to determine if there was a change that it should send a notification. Previously the script pulled width and height before running a "similarity" function. When running the script using opencv4nodejs it fails at width, height, and imagesimilarity saying all the above is not a function.